# How to only include some directories in ctags?

Tags: emacs, ctags, exuberant-ctags

there is an --exclude option but that to exclude the directories/files. I work on a big project and want to only include the directories that has source code and not build stuff.

How to do that? What should I include in my .ctags file?

Answer (score 3):

I use:

```
find FILES | ctags -L -
```

where `FILES` is the appropriate arguments to make `find` return only the files I want to index.

Exuberant Ctags (5.8) is now old and unmaintained, though.  It still works for me, so I've not switched; but the last time I checked "Universal Ctags" appeared to be the way forwards, so I would suggest starting there:

- https://ctags.io
- https://github.com/universal-ctags/ctags

n.b. I experienced a curious bug with Exuberant Ctags 5.8 whereby `find .` resulted in some corrupted tag entries, but `find *` did not; so you *might* want to use the latter if using this approach. I didn't need to index any dot files at the root level, so I'm not sure offhand what happens for  `.*` -- I don't think I tried it. Absolute paths were also fine, but then the TAGS file isn't portable. Potentially not an issue in the newer fork.

Comment: what does the dash after `-L` do?

Comment: @user2183336 Use `man ctags` and see the documentation for the `-L` option.